# How to migrate svn repository to git with svn2git?

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I want to migrate a repository from svn to git. I'm using svn2git from this repository: https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git

When I do :  `svn2git/svn-all-fast-export --rules ruleset/module svn/module`

I get this error:

```
svn: E000002: : Can't open file 'svn/module/format': No such file or directory
```

This Format file does not exist.

Where the svn/module folder is my repository that contains a trunk folder and tags folder, both with files inside.

The ruleset/module file has:

```
create repository module
end repository


match /trunk/module/
  repository module/
  branch master
end match

match /tags/module_(\d+)
  repository module
  branch master
end match
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path to the repo?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon yes, I tried.

Comment: Try removing the '/' from 'repository module/'

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon, same error.

Comment: What version of git and svn are you using? Also you need a catchall at the bottom 'match /'

Answer (score 3):

You are probably trying to convert svn working copy not a repository.
If your repository is hosted at remote location then first create a dump using svnadmin.

```
svnadmin dump
```

Then create a local repo:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repo
```

Check `svnadmin help create` for compatibility options. You might need to use

```
--pre-1.6-compatible
```

Then load the dump `svnadmin load /path/to/repo < dump`

Then you can migrate the newly created local repo.